# Need to split character numbers with comma and space using Java

Tags: java

Hi I am relatively new to Java. I have to compare amount value AED 555,439,972 /yr is lesser to another amount. so I tried to split using the code first

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String value= "AED 555,439,972 /yr";
    String[] tokens = value.split("\b");
    int[] numbers = new int[tokens.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(numbers);

}
```

but I am getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "AED 555,439,972 /yr".

Appreciate if someone can help me to solve the problem.

Comment: You are trying to parse the whole string "AED..." to a number..

Comment: Please explain what you want your code to do, what should the output be?

Answer (score 1):

Hope that you need to get the numeric value from the string.

First, use the following to remove all non-digit characters.

```
value.replaceAll("\\D", "")
```

`\\D` stands for non-digit character. Once every such character is replaced with empty string (which means those are removed), use `Integer.parseInt` on it. (Use `Long.parseLong` if the values can be out of `Integer`'s range.)

In your code, you are trying to split the string by word character ends (which too is not done correctly; you need to escape it as `\\b`). That would give you an array having the result of the string split at each word end (after the AED, after the space following AED, after the first 3 digits, after the first comma and so on..), after which you are converting each of the resulting array components into integers, which would fail at the AED.

In short, the following is what you want:

```
Integer.parseInt(value.replaceAll("\\D", ""));
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few of things wrong with your code:

```
String[] tokens = value.split("\b");
```

The "\" needs to be escape, like this:

```
String[] tokens = value.split("\\b");
```

This will split your input on word boundaries. Only some of the elements in the tokens array will be valid numbers, the others will result in a NumberFormatException. More specifically, at index 2 you'll have "555", at index 4 you'll have 439, and at index 6 you'll have 972. These can be parsed to integers, the others cannot.

Comment: After incorporating your suggestion \\b, now I am getting the error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "AED". Actually my intention is to get the number without any comma or alpha numeric c haracter

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from stack overflow itself

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String line = "AED 555,439,972 /yr";
    String digits = line.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
    System.out.println(digits);
    }
```

the output is 555439972

Answer (score 0):

You are going about it the wrong way. It's a single formatted number, so treat it that way.

Remove all non-digit characters, then parse as an integer:

```
int amount = Integer.parseInt(value.replaceAll("\\D", ""));
```

Then you'll have the number of [dirhams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Arab_Emirates_dirham) per year, which you can compare to other values.